# JAVA8 : convert list of raw data to map of key and list of calculated values

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of raw student data as mentioned below.

```
  [
    {
    section : 1A
    branch : science
    studentName : abc
    marks : 50
    },
    {
    section : 1A
    branch : science
    studentName : sss
    marks : 20
    },
    {
    section : 1A
    branch : science
    studentName : asd
    marks : 40
    },
    {
    section : 1A
    branch : Maths
    studentName : www
    marks : 10
    },
    {
    section : 1A
    branch : Maths
    studentName : abc
    marks : 70
    },
    {
    section : 1A
    branch : Maths
    studentName : abc
    marks : 86
    },
    {
    section : 2A
    branch : Maths
    studentName : abc
    marks : 55
    },
    {
    section : 2A
    branch : Maths
    studentName : abc
    marks : 89
    },
    {
    section : 2A
    branch : Maths
    studentName : abc
    marks :12
    },
  {
    section : 2A
    branch : physical
    studentName : abc
    marks :passed
    },
  {
    section : 2A
    branch : physical
    studentName : abc
    marks :failed
    },
    ]
```

Now I want to transform this data into following format section wise: I am want the minimum marks and max marks for all students for particular subject. Same i want to do across all section. Basically I want to see what is the min and max marks for all the subject across all sections.

I have one more subject "physical test" and value is in pass and fail. I want to know how many are failed including above details. Now i have to declare this variable as String as I may contain actual marks or pass/fail. do you have any suggestions?

```
section 1A:
science : 20-50(min-max)
math : (10-86)(min-max)
section 2S:
science : 20-50(min-max)
math : (12-89)(min-max)
```

I am able to  map sec to listofstudents using below code.

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map2 = studentsList.stream().collect(Collectors
                    .groupingBy(Student::getSection, HashMap::new, Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

I am receiving that value as passed/failed from my source system and I can not change that. I have defined that variable as String as it may contain marks as Integer or string(passed/failed). I have been trying to write clean code using streams with avoiding too many loops and if statements but I am not able to do so. If subject have marks than group them as min-max if subject have passed/failed value than noOfFailed_totalstudents.
I am not able to do it using java streams. Please help. I am also trying it and will update if done.

Comment: How do you represent min and max? Just `20-50` doesn't make any sense. Please refer this and post minimal and reproducible sample first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Ravindra, 20 and 50 are the min and max marks for a particular subject for the section.

Comment: How are you going to store them?

Comment: In a String. Basically I am getting a stream of raw data. I am evaluating that raw data into  JSON and saving it in my file. I am saving marks as subject : min-max on basis of section so I will have the details of subject min max marks for section. Instead of marks i can also have pass/fail as value than I am storing as noOfFails_totalstudens like for physical tests.

Comment: @shershah why don't consider a specific value for *failed* and *passed*?

Comment: I am receiving that value as passed/failed from my source system and I can not change that.  I have defined that variable as String as it may contain marks as Integer or string(passed/failed). I have been trying to write clean code using streams with avoiding too many loops and if statements but I am not able to do so. If subject have marks than group them as min-max if subject have passed/failed value than noOfFailed_totalstudents.

Comment: but what do you want to have in the min max for the passed/failed subjects as min max does not make any sense? do you want to have the amount of those passed vs. failed ie.  20-40(fail-pass)?

Comment: Hi, my some subjects like science value can have marks as 20 marks, 50 marks  or some subject like physical test just passed/failed value. If subject have values than i want min and max marks obtained for a particular subject for a section. but if subject have passed/failed than failed-noOfStudetsFailed. I am getting that data from my source system. I can not do anything about that.

Comment: @HadiJ please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best try. The `Student` class is not really clean. It would be better to model it with two different classes for points related subjects and failed/passed related subjects and use a Factory, but anyway:

```
@Data
public static class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
    private String section;
    private String branch;
    private String studentName;
    private String marks;
    private Integer points;

    public Student(String section, String branch, String studentName, String marks) {
        this.section = section;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        try {
            this.points = Integer.valueOf(marks);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.marks = marks;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        if (o != null){
           if (this.getPoints() != null && o.getPoints() != null){
               return this.getPoints() - o.getPoints();
           } else if (this.getMarks() != null && o.getMarks() != null){
               if (this.getMarks().equalsIgnoreCase(o.getMarks())){
                   return 0;
               } else if (this.getMarks().equals("passed")){
                   return 1;
               } else {
                   return -1;
               }
           }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

then I map the json list in a `Map<String, Map<String, List<Student>>>` instance, where the first map contains the different sections and the second map contains all branches of a given section:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Student>>> map2 = studentList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSection, HashMap::new, 
  Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getBranch, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))));
```

eventually, the map is iterated and for points releated subjects the min/max calculation is done and for failed/passed subjects counting of failed is performed:

```
         map2.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(sm -> sm.getValue().entrySet().stream()) // iterate the sections
            .forEach(b -> {                                   //for each subject
                List<Student> value = b.getValue();
                if (value.size() > 0) {
                    if (value.get(0).getPoints() != null) {
                        //points subjects
                        Collections.sort(value);
                        String out = "Section " + value.get(0).section + ": " + b.getKey() + ": " + value.get(0).getPoints() + "-" + value.get(value.size() - 1).getPoints() + "(min-max)";
                        System.out.println(out);
                    } else if (value.get(0).getMarks() != null) {
                        //failed/passed subjects
                        long failed = value.stream()
                                .filter(s -> s.getMarks().equalsIgnoreCase("failed"))
                                .count();
                        String out = "Section " + value.get(0).section + ": " + b.getKey() + ": " + failed + "-" + value.size() + "(failed-total)";
                        System.out.println(out);
                    }
                }
            });
```

the output is a little bit different from the required one:

```
Section 1A: math: 12-89(min-max)
Section 1A: physics: 2-3(failed-total)
```

Comment: Hi,  I used similar approach, You dont need comparable instead use statistics class for finding min and max. We can use regex to check is value is integer or string. Above expression approach is not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually doing this in a single step by stream API is difficult. so did it in several steps. 
I supposed you have a json string and converted it to an array of `Student` objects.

step1: convert json string to object:

```
class Student {
    private String section;
    private String branch;
    private String studentName;
    private Object marks;
}
```

> `String jsonData = "[{\"section\":\"1A\", \"branch\":\"science\", \"studentName\":\"abc\", \"marks\":50}, {\"section\":\"1A\", \"branch\":\"science\", \"studentName\":\"sss\", \"marks\":20}, {\"section\":\"1A\", \"branch\":\"science\", \"studentName\":\"asd\", \"marks\":40}, {\"section\":\"1A\", \"branch\":\"Maths\", \"studentName\":\"www\", \"marks\":10}, {\"section\":\"1A\", \"branch\":\"Maths\", \"studentName\":\"abc\", \"marks\":70}, {\"section\":\"1A\", \"branch\":\"Maths\", \"studentName\":\"abc\", \"marks\":86}, {\"section\":\"2A\", \"branch\":\"Maths\", \"studentName\":\"abc\", \"marks\":55}, {\"section\":\"2A\", \"branch\":\"Maths\", \"studentName\":\"abc\", \"marks\":89}, {\"section\":\"2A\", \"branch\":\"Maths\", \"studentName\":\"abc\", \"marks\":12},{\"section\":\"2A\", \"branch\":\"physical\", \"studentName\":\"abc\", \"marks\":\"failed\"},{\"section\":\"2A\", \"branch\":\"physical\", \"studentName\":\"abc\", \"marks\":\"passed\"}]";`

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

step2: groupping by `section` and branch properties.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Object>>> map = 
Arrays.stream(objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Student[].class))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSection,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getBranch,
                            Collectors.mapping(Student::getMarks, Collectors.toList()))));
```

step3:

```
List<Statistics> result = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(Statistics::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

for simplifying the logic I've created some classes.

`Statistics` class takes an `Map.Entry<>` as an argument and initial its properties with this argument as bellow.

```
class Statistics {
  private String section;
  private MinMax science;
  private MinMax maths;
  private long totalFailed;

  public Statistics(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<Object>>> entry) {
     this.section = entry.getKey();
     IntSummaryStatistics maths = entry.getValue().getOrDefault("Maths",emptyList())
            .stream()
            .map(o -> Integer.valueOf(o.toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(value -> value));
     this.maths = new MinMax(maths.getMin(), maths.getMax());

     IntSummaryStatistics science = entry.getValue().getOrDefault("science",emptyList())
            .stream()
            .map(o -> Integer.valueOf(o.toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(value -> value));
     this.science = new MinMax(science.getMin(), science.getMax());

     this.totalFailed = entry.getValue()
         .getOrDefault("physical",emptyList())
         .stream()
         .filter(o -> o.toString().equals("failed"))
         .count();
  }
}
```

and

```
class MinMax {
  private Integer min;
  private Integer max;
}
```